# how to make event like button click event for using in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<layoutToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <control:AccTemplate BindModel ="{Binding BindModel, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="50" OnShowDetailEmployee="OnShowDetailEmployeeClicked"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </layoutToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
```

I have list view and custom templage into my xaml file. I'm like to make event to my templete and use the event in xaml. I tried like this, But I'm xaml parse error.

```
 public sealed partial class AccTemplate
{
    public List<AttrOptionModel> Options { get; set; }
    public AttributeModel Attribute { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler OnShowDetailEmployee; OnShowDetailEmployee="OnShowDetailEmployeeClicked"
```

how can make the event?

Comment: You need routed event - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: *But I'm xaml parse error.* Care to share the error message? I wouldn't be surprised if your whole "control:AccTemplate" is rejected anyway for not being a framework element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the event *handler* in the code-behind file of the XAML file where your `DataTemplate` is defined. So if your XAML is called UserControl1.xaml, the event handler should be implemented in UserControl1.xaml.cs.

**UserControl1.xaml.cs:**

```
private void AccTemplate_OnShowDetailEmployee(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

**UserControl1.xaml:**

```
<control:AccTemplate BindModel ="{Binding BindModel, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="50" OnShowDetailEmployee="AccTemplate_OnShowDetailEmployee"/>
```

The event itself is implemented in the control class:

```
public class AccTemplate : UIElement
{
    public List<AttrOptionModel> Options { get; set; }
    public AttributeModel Attribute { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler OnShowDetailEmployee;
}
```